# how to make a popup box using html code

Tags: html

Ok I have not started to code my form yet I know how to build and what code I'm using 
My question is,after the user has hit the submit button how can I make a pop up box appear that says for example your request has been submitted etc.etc...and they hit ok and it takes them back to the home page

Comment: with html you can't either you have use html with css or html and javascript

Comment: do you want us to code it for you?

Comment: SO is not a tutorial website. You post your trial and we will do our best to lead you in the right direction to achieve what you want

Comment: Well I know I'm using CSS for the form but do I have to use a separate for that box as well

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>
     <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup">
                <h2>Here i am</h2>
                <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
                <div class="content">
                    Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: orange;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kzgjr6so/

Comment: Usually we don't encourage coding stuff for people. SO is not a tutorial website. Especially copying a code without giving credit to the main author.

Comment: There's nothing in the rules that prevents people from answering downvoted questions. But I am not looking for rep, just wanting to help someone out. Heck SO even have the Reversal badge, for answering bad questions with a good answer.

Comment: Collective learning & research will help him/her more than having people doing the codes instead...That was all my goal:):)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add action events to a webpage is by using Javascript, a programming language not to be confused with Java. The code below does not take users back to the "home page", but it does show you the general layout of an .html file, and how to use a JavaScript function to make a confirm popup box. A good place to learn more about web design and coding in general is https://www.codecademy.com/.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function confirmBox(){
var yes= confirm("Would you like to proceed to home page")
    if(yes == true){
     // perform some function like taking the user to another page
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Stackoverflow Answer</p>
<button onclick="confirmBox();" class="Button"> Submit </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok yea I know how to do html basic websites this is my first time with forms tho thanks for the Intel turtle